# How can I sort all files by size in a directory?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

How can I display the files in a unix directory sorted by their human readable size, going from largest to smallest?

I tried

```
du -h | sort -V -k 1
```

but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you are expecting the subdirectory sizes to appear in the output too, and also if you are looking for the apparent size of the files or the actual size they use on disk ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`ls(1)` `/sort`:

```
-S     sort by file size
```

Comment: `-S` is no longer a valid sort argument at least on ubuntu. The below answer by @alex worked for me. The answer link is https://superuser.com/a/990437/528836.

Answer (score 40):

```
$ ls -lhS
```

---

```
-l     use a long listing format
-h     with -l, print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
-S     sort by file size
```

Comment: `ls -lhS | grep -v '^d'` - if you want to exclude directories.

Answer (score 18):

If you have the appropriate `sort` version you may simply use:

```
du -h | sort -rh
```

mine is

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.12
```

Answer (score 6):

`du -ha | sort -h`

`du` : estimate file disk usage.

```
-h : for human
-a : all files
```

`sort` : sort lines of text.

```
-h : for human
```

`man du; man sort` for more. It works for me on ubuntu v15.

Answer (score 4):

`ls -S` wasn't an option on the OS for me.  The following worked:
`ls -l | sort -k 5nr`
They "key" was to specify the column to sort (get it, the "key").  Above I'm specifying `-k 5nr` meaning *sort on 5th column which is size (5) evaluated as a number (n) in descending order (n)*

Reference [sort documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(Unix)) for more information

Comment: For a more human readable output, I recommand ```ls -lh | sort -k 5hr```.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work for me:

```
ls -l | sort -g -k 5 -r
```

Which (I just figured-out) is the same as:

```
ls -lS
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `ls -S`, this will properly handle sparse files:

```
ls -lsh | sort -n | sed 's/^[0-9 ]* //'
```